# Get the path to .NET application settings programatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Windows puts .NET app's settings on incredibly obscure paths - our application has them on path:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\COMPANY_NAME\EXECUTABLE_NAME_Url_yhgjvoqwe3bnlu21k1ccbg2qdgwexzsm\1.0.0.0\user.config
```

I often need to migrate the settings on another machine. Writing an import/export feature would be much more work than just copying the file.

How can I get the path to `user.config` from within the code of a .NET application? Eg.:

```
 string settingsPath = Application.GetSettingsPath();
```

Comment: [How do I get the location of the user.config file in programmatically?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9038070)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Huh, how did I miss that? Thanks for the link, I'll try it and mark this question as duplicate.